# Checking for Updates loop after factory reset (Nexus 5)

Tags: updates, nexus-5

I messed around a bit with some system apps and had to factory reset from TWRP recovery. Factory reset was successful, no errors.

Now, when I boot the phone everything seems normal, but after connecting to a wireless network, it gets stuck on the "Looking for Updates" part. I've had it on for at least an hour. I've tried to reboot too, with no luck.